# Why SyntaxError for code after the try/except/finally block in IDLE?

Tags: python, exception, python-idle

I am novice of Python, now learning using the app [SoloLearn](https://www.sololearn.com/)

In the in-app code playground I run these codes with no problem:
[image]

But when I run the same code in IDLE, I get an SyntaxError:
[image]

Does anyone have any idea why?

Comment: Because you're writing directly into the interpreter, and that last print is separate to the previous control structure.

Comment: You must skip an empty line after the last line of the try/except/finally statement.

Comment: @DYZ I try to skipped a line and this still happens

Comment: @jonrsharpe Why is a SyntaxError raised if it is separated from the previous try/except/finally control structure? the last print is of course meant to be after the control structure

Comment: Yes, I know it's after. So keep hitting enter until you see `>>> ` again, not the `... ` continuation. Or write this in a `.py` file and run it, rather than using the repl.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Okay... I think I understand now. If I type directly into the interpreter, it is expecting to run one statement at a time only... Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with IDLE as it is, as others said, the normal behavior of interactive Python, which executes one statement at a time.

```
>>> try:
...   print(10/0)
... except:
...   print(5)
... finally:
...   print(6)
... print(7)
  File "<stdin>", line 7
    print(7)
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

If you put the same code in a file and run the same file in 'batch' mode, it should work fine, whether you run the file from a command line or with IDLE or with any other editor or IDE that will run code in files or an editor buffer.

Since Code Playground has a Run button, I strongly suspect that it is presenting you with an editor window, similar to IDLE and its Run Module F5 menu/shortcut option, not an interactive shell.